# Seasonal data selection in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with time series data in one column and index as a date. The data looks like below: It's from 2000 to 2015.

```
2000-02-24      NaN
2000-02-25      NaN
2000-02-26    0.272
2000-02-27    0.417
2000-02-28    0.837
2000-02-29    1.082
2000-03-01    0.613
2000-03-02    0.709
2000-03-03    0.857
2000-03-04    0.391
2000-03-05    0.470
2000-03-06    0.288
2000-03-07    0.286
```

I want data only from months March to July for each year so is there any way to do that in pandas?

Comment: I think `df[(df.index.month >=2) & (df.index.month<=7)]` should work

Comment: Thank you @EdChum, its works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter using the `DatetimeIndex` attribute [`month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.month.html):

```
df[(df.index.month >=2) & (df.index.month<=6)]
```

months are zero based so `2` corresponds to March and `6` is July